Back-face culling not working
I'm trying to figure out back-face culling, with little results.
My code, from what i've gathered:
    int a = tri[t].t[0], b = tri[t].t[1], c = tri[t].t[2]; // point identifiers from a triangle array
    Point3D pa = draw[a], pb = draw[b], pc = draw[c]; // points of a triangle
    Point3D la = new Point3D(pb.x - pa.x, pb.y - pa.y, pb.z - pa.z); // Line a            
    Point3D lb = new Point3D(pc.x - pa.x, pc.y - pa.y, pc.z - pa.z); // Line b

    Point3D cross = new Point3D(la.y * lb.z - la.z * lb.y, la.z * lb.x - la.x * lb.z, la.x * lb.y - la.y * lb.x);

    cross.x = cross.x * pa.x;
    cross.y = cross.y * pa.y;
    cross.z = cross.z * pa.z;           

    if(cross.z < 0.0){
          // draw triangle
    }

On the left looks like with the above code, after fixing it and adding projection, the culling is broken again, as seen on right.


So what I'm asking is, what am I doing wrong?
A whole example to duplicate gif:

Updated for flexibiilty

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main extends JPanel {
    
    public class LINE {
        public LINE () {
            this.slope = 0.0;
            this.start = 0.0;
            this.steps = 0.0;
            this.end = 0.0;
            this.rev = false;            
        }
        
        public double slope, start, steps, end;
        public boolean rev;

        public void Calc(Point3D from, Point3D to){
            Point3D a = from, b = to;
            double slope = 0.0, steps = 0.0, start = 0.0, end = 0.0;
            boolean rev = false;
            if(a.x != b.x) slope = (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);

            if(a.x != b.x && Math.abs(slope) <= 1.0){
                if(a.x > b.x){
                    a = to;
                    b = from;
                }
                start = a.x;
                end = b.x;
                steps = a.y - slope * a.x;
            } else {
                if(a.y > b.y){
                    a = to;
                    b = from;
                }            
                slope = (b.x - a.x) / (b.y - a.y);
                start = a.y;
                end = b.y;
                steps = a.x - slope * a.y;
                rev = true;
            }   
            this.slope = slope;
            this.end = end;
            this.start = start;
            this.rev = rev;
            this.steps = steps;
        }
    }

    static public class Point3D {
        public Point3D (double x, double y, double z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
        public Point3D (int x, int y, int z) {
            this.x = (double)x;
            this.y = (double)y;
            this.z = (double)z;
        }
        public double x, y, z;
        
    }

    static public class CONT {
        CONT(int a, int b, int c){
            this.t = new int[3];
            t[0] = a;
            t[1] = b;
            t[2] = c;
        }

        public int[] t;

    }
    public Main () {
        
    }

    public static Point3D[] points = new Point3D[8], draw = new Point3D[8], calc = new Point3D[8];
    public static int[][] lines = new int[6][4];
    public static CONT[] tri = new CONT[12];
    public static boolean[] dt = new boolean[12];
    public static Point3D center = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
    public static Point3D rotation = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Dimension size = new Dimension(640, 480);
        Main canvas = new Main();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(size);
        canvas.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(10, 10);
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.setVisible(true);

        points[0] = new Point3D(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
        points[1] = new Point3D(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
        points[2] = new Point3D(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
        points[3] = new Point3D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
        points[4] = new Point3D(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        points[5] = new Point3D(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        points[6] = new Point3D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        points[7] = new Point3D(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        
        draw[0] = new Point3D(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
        draw[1] = new Point3D(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
        draw[2] = new Point3D(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
        draw[3] = new Point3D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
        draw[4] = new Point3D(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        draw[5] = new Point3D(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        draw[6] = new Point3D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        draw[7] = new Point3D(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        calc[0] = new Point3D(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
        calc[1] = new Point3D(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
        calc[2] = new Point3D(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
        calc[3] = new Point3D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
        calc[4] = new Point3D(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        calc[5] = new Point3D(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        calc[6] = new Point3D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        calc[7] = new Point3D(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        
        lines[0][0] = 0;
        lines[0][1] = 1;
        lines[0][2] = 2;
        lines[0][3] = 3;

        lines[1][0] = 4;
        lines[1][1] = 5;
        lines[1][2] = 6;
        lines[1][3] = 7;

        lines[2][0] = 0;
        lines[2][1] = 4;
        lines[2][2] = 7;
        lines[2][3] = 3;

        lines[3][0] = 1;
        lines[3][1] = 5;
        lines[3][2] = 6;
        lines[3][3] = 2;

        lines[4][0] = 0;
        lines[4][1] = 4;
        lines[4][2] = 5;
        lines[4][3] = 1;

        lines[5][0] = 3;
        lines[5][1] = 7;
        lines[5][2] = 6;
        lines[5][3] = 2;

        tri[0] = new CONT(0, 1, 3);
        tri[1] = new CONT(1, 2, 3);
        tri[2] = new CONT(0, 4, 7);
        tri[3] = new CONT(0, 3, 7);
        tri[4] = new CONT(1, 5, 2);
        tri[5] = new CONT(2, 6, 5);
        tri[6] = new CONT(4, 5, 7);
        tri[7] = new CONT(5, 6, 7);
        tri[8] = new CONT(0, 4, 1);
        tri[9] = new CONT(4, 5, 1);
        tri[10] = new CONT(3, 7, 2);
        tri[11] = new CONT(7, 6, 2);

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            center.x += points[i].x;
            center.y += points[i].y;
            center.z += points[i].z;
        }
        center.x /= 8;
        center.y /= 8;
        center.z /= 8;
        while(true){         
            RotatePoints();     
            canvas.repaint();
            try{
            Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(125, 23, 238));
        LINE line = new LINE();
        for(int t = 0; t < 12; t++){
            int a = tri[t].t[0], b = tri[t].t[1], c = tri[t].t[2]; // point identifiers from a triangle array
            Point3D pa = calc[a], pb = calc[b], pc = calc[c]; // points of a triangle
            Point3D la = new Point3D(pb.x - pa.x, pb.y - pa.y, pb.z - pa.z); // Line a            
            Point3D lb = new Point3D(pc.x - pa.x, pc.y - pa.y, pc.z - pa.z); // Line b

            Point3D cross = new Point3D(la.y * lb.z - la.z * lb.y, la.z * lb.x - la.x * lb.z, la.x * lb.y - la.y * lb.x);
            double e = Math.sqrt(cross.x * cross.x + cross.y * cross.y + cross.z * cross.z);
            cross.z /= e;
            dt[t] = (cross.z < 0.0);
            //cross.z /= e;
            /*
            double size = 20.0;
            */
        }
        double size = 120.0;
        for(int p = 0; p < 8; p++){
            draw[p].x = calc[p].x * size + 250.0;
            draw[p].y = calc[p].y * size + 250.0;
            draw[p].z = calc[p].z * size + 250.0;
        }

        for(int t = 0; t < 12; t++){
            if(dt[t]){   
                int a = tri[t].t[0], b = tri[t].t[1], c = tri[t].t[2]; // point identifiers from a triangle array
                Point3D pa = draw[a], pb = draw[b], pc = draw[c]; // points of a triangle
                line.Calc(pa, pb);
                for(; line.start < line.end; line.start += 1.0){
                    double w = line.slope * line.start + line.steps;
                    if(line.rev){
                        g.drawRect((int)w, (int)line.start, 1, 1);
                    } else {
                        g.drawRect((int)line.start, (int)w, 1, 1);
                    }
                }
                
                line.Calc(pb, pc);
                for(; line.start < line.end; line.start += 1.0){
                    double w = line.slope * line.start + line.steps;
                    if(line.rev){
                        g.drawRect((int)w, (int)line.start, 1, 1);
                    } else {
                        g.drawRect((int)line.start, (int)w, 1, 1);
                    }
                }
                line.Calc(pc, pa);
                for(; line.start < line.end; line.start += 1.0){
                    double w = line.slope * line.start + line.steps;
                    if(line.rev){
                        g.drawRect((int)w, (int)line.start, 1, 1);
                    } else {
                        g.drawRect((int)line.start, (int)w, 1, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        

    }

    public static void RotatePoints(){
        rotation.x += 0.25;
        rotation.y += 0.5;
        rotation.z += 0.75;

        double sx = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.x)), sy = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)), sz = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.z));
        double cx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.x)), cy = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)), cz = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.z));
        center = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            Point3D spot = points[i];//new Point3D(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
            calc[i].y = (cx * (spot.y - center.y) - sx * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.y;
            calc[i].z = (sx * (spot.y - center.y) + cx * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.z;
            spot = new Point3D(spot.x, calc[i].y, calc[i].z);
            calc[i].x = (cy * (spot.x - center.x) - sy * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.x;
            calc[i].z = (sy * (spot.x - center.x) + cy * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.z;
            spot = new Point3D(calc[i].x, calc[i].y, calc[i].z);
            calc[i].x = (cz * (spot.x - center.x) - sz * (spot.y - center.y)) + center.x;
            calc[i].y = (cz * (spot.y - center.y) + sz * (spot.x - center.x)) + center.y;
        }    
    }

}


I don't know why you're multiplying cross by pa — can you clarify what the reasoning for that is, or what source suggested to do that?

@DMGregory It is just what I ended up with, was just playing around with variables hoping to get a better result.

What behaviour do you see without that? Can you record a fresh gif?

@DMGregory The behaviour is, from what I can tell without posting another gif, exactly the same. I can't tell the difference.

Next thing to check: are your cube's triangles wound the right way? Can you share the vertex/index data you're using?

@DMGregory Those can be found on the whole code example at the end of the post. new CONT([0], [1], [2]) // triangle data I tried setting the triangles clockwise or counter-clockwise or just randomly, still ended up with relatively the same result as seen on the gif.

Your triangles have a mix of clockwise and counterclockwise winding.
Try these indices instead, which should all have the same winding:
tri[0] = new CONT(0, 1, 3);
tri[1] = new CONT(1, 2, 3);
tri[2] = new CONT(0, 7, 4);
tri[3] = new CONT(0, 3, 7);
tri[4] = new CONT(1, 5, 2);
tri[5] = new CONT(2, 5, 6);
tri[6] = new CONT(4, 6, 5);
tri[7] = new CONT(4, 7, 6);
tri[8] = new CONT(0, 4, 1);
tri[9] = new CONT(4, 5, 1);
tri[10] = new CONT(3, 2, 7);
tri[11] = new CONT(7, 2, 6);

You can also delete these lines, since they don't change the sign of cross.z:
 double e = Math.sqrt(cross.x * cross.x + cross.y * cross.y + cross.z * cross.z);
 cross.z /= e;


This worked very well, and now the cubes cull accordingly. Next step I tried adding projection, which sort of broke the culling, every triangle but the front are drawn.

Flip the sign of your cross.z test or reverse the winding of the triangles then.
